# Using node.js and natural language processing to handle multiple word phrases

Tags: javascript, node.js, nlp

I'm using the very cool [natural](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural) library for node.js.

I'm trying to train my classifier to match the phrase `user experience`.  My issue is if I do something like this:

```
classifier.addDocument(['user experience'], 'ux');
```

It doesn't match 2 word phrases, I believe because it tokenizes the words.  If I do something like this:

```
classifier.addDocument(['user', 'experience'], 'ux');
```

It works like I want it to, but my issue is, I don't want to just match on the word `user` because an article could mention include the word `user` multiple times and it would potentially have nothing to do with user experience, which would lead to inaccurate classifications.  So, my question is how does one match 2 or more word phrases using NLP?

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: Is this not possible with NLP or should I look in a different direction?

Comment: Hi @bababa, I'm having the same issue, what was you final solution for this? Thanks :)

Comment: Didn't really find one that worked.  @jedanput's answer below did not not work for me.  Using an array for bigrams did not produce the expected result I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

You should take a look at n-grams, specifically in this case it's called a bigram, a sequence of two tokens.
https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural#bigrams

I haven't used that particular library (don't think nodejs is the best language for NLP, it's still in its early stage and I'd suggest you use a more mature library(NLTK)/language(python) for NLP. Though I guess it's fine just for testing or some small project).

Anyway, judging from the manual, you could maybe do something like

```
classifier.addDocument([['user', 'experience']], 'ux');
```

Add brackets for each sequence you wish to add together.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late but...

I use Natural and I think you don't need to pass an array, simply do:

```
classifier.addDocument('user experience', 'ux');
```

That should work. Basically just remove the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to this is treat your text as an array of objects. Like this:

```js
var natural = require('natural');
var classifier = //Here comes the classifier that you had to choose
    
var trainingData = [{text: 'user experience', label: 'ux'}]

var yourTestData = [];

trainingData.forEach(function(item){
  // finally you add the data to classifier
  classifier.addDocument(item.text, item.label);  
});
```